# Sending an http url as a request parameter in post request

Tags: http, curl, http-post

I am trying to make a post request using curl. One of the parameters in the  end-point i have defined is supposed to be an absolute url that I can copy and paste from the browser. The url will look something like this:

http://myApplication.com/query/query2?parameter1=value1&parameter2=value2#someHash

Now this seems pretty straightforward, so I tried to pass this as a string
-d "url='http://myApplication.com/query/query2?parameter1=value1&parameter2=value2#someHash'" in my curl command,  but I am receiving null in the url. Can someone please tell me the correct way to pass this url to my end-point? :\

Answer (score 0):

It probably wants it URL encoded. Try:

```
curl --data-urlencode "url=[your pasted URL]" [where-to-post]
```